# Genrics in Linq using Multiple Where Clause

Tags: linq, generics, linq-to-sql

I need to write a generic search method which i could use multiple times. My method is:

```
public List<GoldMakers> listofRecoverd_Reuse(int? EmployeeID, DateTime? Startdate, DateTime? EndDate)
    {
    List<GoldMakers> RecoveredGold = db.GoldMakers.Include(e => e.tbl_Employees)
        .Where(x => (x.R_Employee_ID == EmployeeID || EmployeeID == null) 
        && (x.R_Date >= Startdate || Startdate == null) && (x.R_Date <= EndDate || EndDate == null)).ToList();
    return RecoveredGold;
}
```

I know it could be achieved using Generics, but i don't know how to work with linq using Generics.

```
public List<T> search<T>(T modelClass, int? EmployeeID, DateTime? Startdate, DateTime? EndDate)
{
    list<T> result = db.Table<T>().where ........
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below:

```
public List<T> search<T>(DbSet<T> modelClass, int? EmployeeID, DateTime? Startdate, DateTime? EndDate)  where T : class, new()
{
    list<T> result = modelClass.where ........
    return result;
}
```

You can call it like below

```
var tbl1 = search(db.table1, param1, param2, param3);
var tbl2 = search(db.table2, param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: what if i have to use include or orderby?

Comment: You want to do this in that common search or after calling that ?

Comment: I could use some external parameter for Order purpose, like i want to order the result with its primary key ID and Includes are common..